# DataBind attributes of custom component to ViewModel of a Fragment?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

So I'm trying to create a custom component that consists of two labels and one TextInputLayout views. When I implement it in my fragment I want to bind visibility of one label, colour of TextInputLayout boxStroke and text inside TextInputLayout to viewModel MutableLiveData variables. But somehow I can't get it to work, can anybody help?

**My custom component layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_input_label"
            style="@style/BasicText"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_normal"
            android:text="@string/first_name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/custom_input_layout"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_normal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_normal"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:errorTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:helperTextEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/custom_input_label">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/custom_edit_text"
                style="@style/InputTextStyle" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_input_error"
            style="@style/ErrorText"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_normal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_11dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:text="@string/first_name_error"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/custom_input_layout" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</merge>
```

**My CustomView class**

```
class CustomInputField @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleRes) {
    

    init {
        val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

        inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_text_input, this)
    }
}
```

**My MutableLiveData inside ViewModel**

```
  private val _nameErrorVisibility = MutableLiveData(View.GONE)
  val nameErrorVisibility: LiveData<Int> = _nameErrorVisibility


  private val _nameBoxColor =
      MutableLiveData(R.color.mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color)
  val nameBoxColor: LiveData<Int> = _nameBoxColor
```

**AND BASICALLY THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO DO IN MY FRAGMENT LAYOUT**

```
<ba.project.project.ui.base.view.CustomInputField
                    android:id="@+id/txtFirstName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:boxColor="@{context.getColor(viewModel.nameBoxColor)}"
                    app:errorText="@string/first_name_error"
                    app:errorVisibility="@{viewModel.nameErrorVisibility}"
                    app:inputText="@={viewModel.firstName}"
                    app:labelText="@string/first_name"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```